# How to get email addres from PeoplePicker field using C# and Client Object model

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject, peoplepicker

I am using CAML to retrieve some sharepoint list items. On of the columns is a PeoplePicker control. How can I extract the email address from this column?

I know how to get the LookupValue and LookupID, but not the email.

```
FieldUserValue usvSM1 = i["Account"] as FieldUserValue;
Console.WriteLine(usvSM1.LookupValue);
```

Keep in mind that I'm programming against the client object model.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var user = web.SiteUsers.GetById(usvSM1.LookupId);

context.Load(user);
context.ExecuteQuery();

Console.WriteLine(user.Email);
```

EDIT:
Web.SiteUsers property is available only SharePoint 2013 client object model.

Second way you can try to get user:

```
var user = web.EnsureUser(usvSM1.LookupValue);

context.Load(user);
context.ExecuteQuery();

Console.WriteLine(user.Email);
```

Comment: Thanks Yevgeniy - I think the SiteUsers cannot be used with client object model.
[link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.siteusers.aspx

Comment: Hm, which version of SharePoint are you using? Seems like SharePoint 2013 has this property but SharePoint 2010 does not. Check here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web_members(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Cool stuff! :) This works perfectly. I think my organization will upgrade to SP2013 sometime this year - not just yet. Thanks a lot Yevgeniy!! :)

Comment: hi @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets, what if the display name of two employees remains the same?  for example:  "john smith",  and "john, smith", but with their email is having johns1@domain.com and johns2@domain.com, so, there will be a conflict in identifying the person/email of by sharepoint? how to handle this situation

Answer (score 0):

```
        FieldUserValue [] fTo = oListItem["People picker field name"]  as FieldUserValue[];
            var userTo = clientContext.Web.SiteUsers.GetById(fTo[0].LookupId);
            clientContext.Load(userTo);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            headers.To.Add(userTo.Email);
```

Comment: here how to get the display name and trimmed login name? user.Title throws an erro r.